# Inserting multiple page headers to crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there any way to insert more than one page header to crystal reports **without repeating the group header**.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Can you elaborate? You can right click the section and `insert section below` to create `page header b, c, d`... etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong , you want to add multiple page header in same report.
If yes then, simply right click on **Insert Section Below**. it will add as page header section in crystal report.
And add page header section as much as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can insert multiple page header in your report as per your requirement. Follow the below steps:
Right click on "Report Header" >> Goto "Section Expert" >> Select "Page Header" >> Select "Insert"

You can select Insert multiple times and hence can insert multiple Page headers.